# Issue with if statement pulling incorrect data from database

Tags: php

I own a tournament script and i had a report system built into the script. Below is the code.

```
$this_search=array();

switch($t['bracket_size']) {

case 8:
$games_count=8;
$rounds_count=3;
break;

case 16:
$games_count=16;
$rounds_count=4;
break;

case 32:
$games_count=32;
$rounds_count=5;
break;

case 64:
$games_count=64;
$rounds_count=6;
break;

case 128:
$games_count=128;
$rounds_count=7;
break;

}

for($rounds = $rounds_count; $rounds > 0; $rounds--) 
{
for($games = $games_count; $games > 0; $games--)  
{
    if($b["w_r".$rounds."_s".$games.""]==$my_team_info['team_id']) {
        $this_search['round']=$rounds;    
        $this_search['game']=$games;   
        break; 
    } 
} 
}  

if (
$this_search['round']=='') {$smarty->assign('error', "Sorry, we couldn't find your match. Contact Live Support."); 
}else{

$match_check=d_c("select * from tournaments_reports where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'"); 
if ($match_check==0) {} 
    else{
$match_check_info=d("select * from tournaments_reports where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'");     
    if ($match_check_info['team_A']==$my_team_info['team_id'] or $match_check_info['team_B']==$my_team_info['team_id']) { 
        $smarty->assign('error', "Sorry, your team has already reported this match. If this is an error, contact live support.");  
    } 

} 
}



if ($_POST[submit])
{
    if ($match_check==0) {$ins=d_i("INSERT INTO `tournaments_reports` (`id`, `tid`, `team_A`, `team_B`, `team_A_report`, `team_B_report`, `team_A_time`, `team_B_time`, `round`, `game`) VALUES ('', '$t[id]', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$this_search[round]', '$this_search[game]')");}   

if ($_POST[report]==1) { 
    // LOSS
    if ($match_check[team_A]==''){   
        $update=d_u("update tournaments_reports set team_A='$my_team_info[team_id]',team_A_report='2',team_A_time='".time()."' where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'");  
    }
    elseif ($match_check[team_B]==''){  
        $update=d_u("update tournaments_reports set team_B='$my_team_info[team_id]',team_B_report='2',team_B_time='".time()."' where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'");
    } 
} 
elseif ($_POST[report]==2) {
    // WIN
    if ($match_check[team_A]==''){  
        $update=d_u("update tournaments_reports set team_A='$my_team_info[team_id]',team_A_report='1',team_A_time='".time()."' where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'"); 
    }
    elseif ($match_check[team_B]==''){ 
        $update=d_u("update tournaments_reports set team_B='$my_team_info[team_id]',team_B_report='1',team_B_time='".time()."' where tid='$t[id]' and round='$this_search[round]' and game='$this_search[game]'");
    }
}

$smarty->assign('success', "Thank you for your report.");
}
```

The code is supposed to search through the bracket database (`$b`) for the round and game that the user is currently in.

The code (not included) then displays and allows the user to report their scores for the round and game that they are currently in.

The above code is selecting incorrect column to pull the rounds and game count from.

Example:
My team is in round 1 game 2 
i have been advanced to round 2 game 1
When i go to report the scored for round 2 game 1 i receive an error saying "You have already reported the round1 game 2 scores"

I am now in round 2 game 1 so it should allow me to report for that round and game but it does not. I figured out that it is the code above that needs changing but I do not know exactly what needs to be changed or altered.

Comment: This portion of your code is not querying your db or producing an error message.  You should probably post the portion of your code that is generating the actual error message as well as the db queries

Comment: @jacob I have included all code used on the report page.